# scp: using specific NIC

Tags: ssh, networking, scp, openssh

I am trying to achieve to perform scp via specific NIC.

I read [SCP man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) but couldn't find required flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`BindAddress`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#BindAddress) or [`BindInterface`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#BindInterface) options using [`-o` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#o).

For example:

```
scp -o BindAddress=x.x.x.x ...
```